# MS SQL Server 2008 error 17058, when debuging .dll C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, debugging

I have a problem.

I'm trying to debug .dll with external stored procedure for MS SQL 2008 x64 in Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 8.1 (UAC turned off, full-access opened for "MS SQL Server" folder).

```
1. I stop Server service
2. include <srv.h> amd export an xp_func from library
3. Project properties of MS VS
      a. post built-in event:
         Copy "C:\...\x.dll" "C:\...\MSSQL\Binn\"
      b. Debugging Command:
         C:\...\sqlserv.exe -c
4. Start the project and open "Server Management Studio" to write a script,
   that call a xp_func.
```

Yesterday it worked and I could debug the library.
Now I can't - there is an error message 17058 in sqlserv.exe !only in MS VS console!,
that server can't access a ERRLOG file in "C:...\MSSQL\LOG\" folder, because
it is busy by another process. What process? I do not know...

How can I handle this problem? And continue debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I've given to myself all rights of folders in ProgramFiles. **I've checked mark 'to start as admin' in 'serv.exe' file**. Then start MS VS as admin. Problem has been disappeared.

It is not elegant solution, but it works.